# With css, how to ensure wrap on span boundary?

Tags: html, css

To display tags for a blog post, I have a div with a bunch of spans. I want any span to always show on one line (with ellipsis if too long is ok). How do I enable this with css?

```
<div>
  <span class='tag'>math</span>
  <span class='tag'>physics</span>
  <span class='tag'>mathematical induction</span>
  <span class='tag'>theoretical physics</span>
</div
```

I don't want the span to break between `mathematical` and `induction`, or between `theoretical` and `physics`. My tag spans have styling to make them stand apart:

```
.tag {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 400%;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CSS Method

```
white-space: nowrap
```

So your css look like

```
.tag {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 400%;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

## Use Non breakable Space

on the user side you could just use `&nbsp`.

For better readability I would always prefer the first method.

Comment: I agree - the css method is better than modifying the strings - I will accept this answer as soon as it lets me (says I have to wait 6 minutes, no idea why)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very CSS related, you can use unbreakable space `&nbsp;`.

For example:

```
<span class="tag">mathematical&nbsp;induction</span>
```